# SASS nesting causing too many specific selectors for IE

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I've somewhat recently made the switch to SASS for writing my CSS. I build sites in Wordpress. I've developed a CSS-writing method that I thought was a smart way to organize CSS by specific Wordpress "page." My method is:

1) through some php magic, I give every new Wordpress "page" a unique class all the way up in the body tag. So if my site has 4 pages, the body tag on each page has a unique class as so: 
    , , etc...

I thought this would give me a great "shortcut" for styling CSS elements that appear on multiple pages but that I need styled a bit differently on each page. For example, let's say I have this markup on all 4 pages of my site:

```
<section class="module">
    <div class="price">
        <div class="cenetered">
            <p>some text <span>text</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

BUT, I need that span inside the p tag to be styled differently on page 4. Easy, I thought. I my SASS, I would just use my unique page body class and do this:

```
.page1, .page2, .page3 {

    .module {
        color:red;

        .price {
            color:blue;

            .centered {
                color:green;

                p span {color:yellow}

            }
        }   
    }
}

.page4 {

    .module {
        color:black;

        .price {
            color:black;

            .centered {
                color:black;

                p span {color:black}

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

So the first SASS block is for my first 3 pages, and the second block is for my 4th page. It styles everything exactly how I want it, and make organizational sense to me to basically mimic my html nesting with my SASS nesting. Of course, since I'm so specific with my SASS nesting, if I want to override a CSS rule further down my SASS page, I need to be just as specific with my nesting (or use the !important rule, which I like to avoid).

I thought everything was fine with this method -- looked great in all my browsers, until I looked on IE9. I noticed in IE9 developer tools that my CSS file was just "stopping" halfway down and half of my rules weren't even being loaded. I inspected more and I noticed my SASS method was outputting a HUGE number of selectors/rules for each element I'm trying to style.

The above example for that span tag within the .page1, .page2, .page3 nesting alone is outputting dozens of rules. I sort of realized this would happen, but I didn't think it was problematic since my CSS was 100% valid.

So my questions are:

1. Is this just a terrible method of writing CSS? (Do I need to rewrite everything to eliminate so much nesting?)
2. Why does IE9 (and under) just stop reading my CSS if it comes to a CSS rule with too many selectors?

I've used various "selector counter" tools and according to them, my CSS sheet is well under the limit that IE9 imposes: they tell me my stylesheet has 1744 selectors.

Here is my sheet: http://wallstreetprep2.com/wp-content/themes/wallstreetprep/style.css

I'm fearing I need to just rewrite my SASS and get rid of nesting up to the body tag level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deep SASS nesting, if not written with a goal of ending up with "the least amount of necessary selectors" in your CSS stylesheet can certainly lead to a large amount of css selectors.

All non-IE browsers seem able to read an entire CSS stylesheet no matter how many selectors or rules it contains, but IE9 simply stops reading the stylesheet after 4095 rules: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx

My solution was to simply reduce my nesting, and IE read the stylesheet just fine. Minor nesting reduction — using a general rule of "don't nest more than 4 deep" eliminated a HUGE amount of rules in the resulting CSS.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is this just a terrible method of writing CSS? (Do I need to rewrite everything to eliminate so much nesting?)*

If some markup have base style for the most of the pages then there's no need to wrap the all `.module` inside `.page1, .page2, .page3` selectors.

I would rather suggest to use (as a general approach) short and less specific selectors for the basic style

```
.module {
    color : red;
    .price {

    }        
}
```

and then override the style for the exceptions, wrapping the `.module` class into `.page4`

```
.page4 {
    .module {
       color : red;
       .price {
          ...
       }        
    }
}
```

---

> *Why does IE9 (and under) just stop reading my CSS if it comes to a CSS rule with too many selectors? *

It could be a parsing problem maybe due to one or more of these [392 validation errors](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css21&warning=0&uri=http://wallstreetprep2.com/wp-content/themes/wallstreetprep/style.css) inside the stylesheet and/or probably to the presence of huge rules `4400` characters long generated with SASS, e.g.

```
.selfstudy .products ul li .module h2 .courseicon, .selfstudy
.products ul li .bluemodule h2 .courseicon, .selfstudy .products ul li
.page-template-page- 1col-php .customersspeak .speak_small p h2
.courseicon, .page-template-page- 1col-php .customersspeak
.speak_small .selfstudy .products ul li p h2 .courseicon, .selfstudy
.products ul li .wspblog #sidebar .widget_text h2 .courseicon,
.wspblog #sidebar .selfstudy .products ul li .widget_text h2
.courseicon, .selfstudy .products ul li .single-blogposts #sidebar
.widget_text h2 .courseicon, .single-blogposts #sidebar .selfstudy
.products ul li .widget_text h2 .courseicon, .selfstudy .products ul
li .archive #sidebar .widget_text h2 .courseicon, .archive #sidebar
.selfstudy .products ul li .widget_text h2 .courseicon, .selfstudy
.products ul li .page-id-2310 .pricebox h2 .courseicon, .page-id-2310
.selfstudy .products ul li .pricebox h2 .courseicon, .selfstudy
.products ul li .page-id-2406 .pricebox h2 .courseicon, .page-id-2406
.selfstudy .products ul li .pricebox h2 .courseicon, .selfstudy
.products ul li .excel a[title="pdf"] h2 .courseicon, .excel
.selfstudy .products ul li a[title="pdf"] h2 .courseicon, .selfstudy
.products ul li .excel a[title="pdf2"] h2 .courseicon, .excel
.selfstudy .products ul li a[title="pdf2"] h2 .courseicon, .selfstudy
.products ul li .mycourses form h2 .courseicon, .mycourses .selfstudy
.products ul li form h2 .courseicon, .mycourses .products ul li
.module h2 .courseicon, .mycourses .products ul li .bluemodule h2
.courseicon, .mycourses .products ul li .page- template-page-1col-php
.customersspeak .speak_small p h2 .courseicon, .page- template-page-
1col-php .customersspeak .speak_small .mycourses .products ul li p h2
.courseicon, .mycourses .products ul li .wspblog #sidebar .widget_text
h2 .courseicon, .wspblog #sidebar .mycourses .products ul li
.widget_text h2 .courseicon, .mycourses .products ul li .single-
blogposts #sidebar .widget_text h2 .courseicon, .single-blogposts
#sidebar .mycourses .products ul li .widget_text h2 .courseicon,
.mycourses .products ul li .archive #sidebar .widget_text h2
.courseicon, .archive #sidebar .mycourses .products ul li .widget_text
h2 .courseicon,  .mycourses .products ul li .page-id-2310 .pricebox h2
.courseicon, .page-id-2310 .mycourses .products ul li .pricebox h2
.courseicon, .mycourses .products ul li .page-id-2406 .pricebox h2
.courseicon, .page-id-2406 .mycourses .products ul li .pricebox h2
.courseicon, .mycourses .products ul li .excel a[title="pdf"] h2
.courseicon, .excel .mycourses .products ul li a[title="pdf"] h2
.courseicon, .mycourses .products ul li .excel a[title="pdf2"] h2
.courseicon, .excel .mycourses .products ul li a[title="pdf2"] h2
.courseicon, .mycourses .products ul li form h2 .courseicon, .single-
partnerpages .products ul li .module h2 .courseicon, .single-
partnerpages .products ul li .bluemodule h2 .courseicon, .single-
partnerpages .products ul li .page-template-page-1col-php
.customersspeak .speak_small p h2 .courseicon, .page-template-page-
1col-php .customersspeak .speak_small .single-partnerpages .products
ul li p h2 .courseicon, .single-partnerpages .products ul li .wspblog
#sidebar .widget_text h2 .courseicon, .wspblog #sidebar .single-
partnerpages .products ul li .widget_text h2 .courseicon, .single-
partnerpages .products ul li .single-blogposts #sidebar .widget_text
h2 .courseicon, .single-blogposts #sidebar .single-partnerpages
.products ul li .widget_text h2 .courseicon, .single-partnerpages
.products ul li .archive #sidebar .widget_text h2 .courseicon,
.archive #sidebar .single-partnerpages .products ul li .widget_text h2
.courseicon, .single-partnerpages .products ul li .page- id-2310
.pricebox h2 .courseicon, .page-id-2310 .single-partnerpages .products
ul li .pricebox h2 .courseicon, .single-partnerpages .products ul li
.page- id-2406 .pricebox h2 .courseicon, .page-id-2406 .single-
partnerpages .products ul li .pricebox h2 .courseicon, .single-
partnerpages .products ul li .excel a[title="pdf"] h2 .courseicon,
.excel .single-partnerpages .products ul li a[title="pdf"] h2
.courseicon, .single-partnerpages .products ul li .excel
a[title="pdf2"] h2 .courseicon, .excel .single-partnerpages .products
ul li a[title="pdf2"] h2 .courseicon, .single-partnerpages .products
ul li .mycourses form h2 .courseicon, .mycourses .single-partnerpages
.products ul li form h2 .courseicon
```

Comment: I believe it is due to the huge amount of rules. I'm actually not getting any validation errors at all, just warnings -- the css is 100% valid (CSS level 3) -- and IE9 supports CS3 just fine. I went through my css and simply deleted (just for testing) these huge chunks and IE9 then loaded my complete stylesheet. It just seems silly that IE would impose a limit on valid css selectors. I don't imagine it's actually slowing the browser down since most of these rules are not actually being applied to anything. They're just "extra fat" so to speak...